# Visual Studio VB.NET: Query gives unexpected results

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm in Visual Studio 2013 working on a VB.NET desktop app.
I added a simple query to the dataset which goes like this:

```
SELECT ID, DateStamp, RegNum, Make, Model, Year
FROM TblWof
WHERE (Make LIKE '%' + @Param1 + '%')
```

called with:

```
Me.TblWofTableAdapter.FillByMaker(Me.WofManDBDataSet.TblWof, TextBox1.Text)
```

If I give Honda as search param I get all the Honda makes back in the results.
However; If I give H, or Hon, or da I get nothing back. What's happening?

The SQL Server column definition for 'Make' is `nchar(10)`,

Comment: You need to find out what datatype `Me.TblWofTableAdapter.FillByMaker` creates when it build the parameter, thats the only thing I can see that would cause an issue.

Comment: I changed the data type in the SQL table designer and the query (inside dataset query properties) to nvarchar and the problem went away. I don't know who to award the answer to since you have both hinted at the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty rare that `nchar` is a good choice. In your case, every value MUST be 10 characters long, which means that anything passed in that isn't will be padded with spaces. I'm guessing that what you're seeing is related to that. If you change the data type to `nvarchar` then I don't think that you'll see the same issue. That will also have the advantage that you won't have trailing spaces on the data when you retrieve it from the database.

It may not matter but, if you're going to use a Unicode data type for the column, you really ought to use a Unicode data type for anything you concatenate with it or compare to it, i.e.

```sql
SELECT ID, DateStamp, RegNum, Make, Model, Year
FROM TblWof
WHERE (Make LIKE N'%' + @Param1 + N'%')
```

Comment: In SSMS OP's code works, regardless of nchar - but I totally agree its a rare choice for datatype.

Comment: In the end I switched to nvarchar and it works ok. I don't know who to award the answer to since you have both hinted at the same thing. Sorry I'm new here :) However, thanks for your help :)

Comment: @MrDev, I think I may have done more than "hinted". ;-)